# visual scrollbar plugin for eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm looking for visual scroll bar for eclipse, something like [RockScroll](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingRockScroll.aspx) Does anybody knows one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two options I have found:

- minimap plugin: https://github.com/apauzies/eclipse-minimap-view
- overview plugin: http://sandipchitale.blogspot.se/2013/02/overview-plugin-for-eclipse.html

Sadly none of these two scale the way I would like to, I would like it to scale to show the entire file even for large files but these only scale to a limit as far as I understand.

Comment: Which one of them do you personally prefer?

Comment: They are very similar... But the overview plugin seems a little more mature.